# Using ne + plus que vs. ne + que

Tags: négation, double-négation

I've realized I'm a bit fuzzy on using ne + plus que versus ne + que, and I'm having a surprisingly hard time finding help on Google.

For example, how would "il ne manque plus que ça" differ from "il ne manque que ça"? Could y'all give me some other examples of using "ne plus que" vs. "ne que"?

Merci !

Comment: Not that the sentence “il ne manque plus que ça” is particular because it has an idiomatic meaning in some contexts. It is used to express exasperation about (yet) an other problem. The conditional mood can also be used when anticipating one.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez  rather "il ne manquait plus que ça", and as you point it: "il ne manquerait plus que ça"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using "plus" in this case indicates that at some other time you were also missing other things.

For example: "Il ne manquait que X et Y et maintenant il ne manque plus que X."