# What is the meaning of "ne ... plus que"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, négation, double-négation

> « Il **ne** reste **plus qu**'un de ces trucs. »

I understand that "**ne ... plus**" means "**no longer**" while "**ne ... que**" means "**only**".

The thing is that every now and then I come across sentences that include *both* of these expressions. I wonder if the sentence above means:

> "Now, only one of those things remains."

At any rate, how do you naturally translate the expression "**ne ... plus que**" into English? I’ve read over a similar question, but I’m still none the wiser.

[Using ne + plus que vs. ne + que](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16527/using-ne-plus-que-vs-ne-que)

Comment: To clarify, do you want to translate it into English so that you understand the meaning of the French sentence better?

Comment: Hi, I'm not particularly into translating this sentence, but rather I'm hoping to get a firm grip on when to use "ne ... que" or "ne ... plus que" .

Comment: Perhaps a good follow-up to your good question (or maybe even an addition to it) to focus on the value of “[ne] … **plus**” would be asking if both of the following are grammatically correct and if so, what’s the difference in meaning between them: «Il ne reste plus qu'un [seul] de ces trucs» (with “plus”) and «Il ne reste qu'un [seul] de ces trucs» (without “plus”).

Comment: Pour alimenter la discussion, voir aussi [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/plus/61813), TLFi ([_plus_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plus), [_guère_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/guère)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand that "*ne ... plus*" means "no longer" while "*ne ... que*" means "only".

This is correct. "*Ne ... plus que*" emphasizes that, though there were several before, there is only one left.

There is **no longer** several items, **only** one remains.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure what exactly "plus" means here: "ONLY one MORE remains" or "they NO LONGER remain BUT/EXCEPT one." It looks like the latter was the correct interpretation.

Comment: I guess both would be acceptable translations, but I understand it rather like your second proposal, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> Il *ne* reste *plus qu*'un de ces trucs :

- Avant il y avait plusieurs 'trucs', maintenant il en reste un seul (il *n*'en reste *plus qu*'un) : le *plus* insiste sur l'unicité de *ce qui reste* parmi les 'trucs' (mais il peut rester d'autres objets qui ne sont pas des 'trucs').
- Il y a une notion de valorisation - positive ou négative - de la situation.

  > De tous les objets qui restent ici, il en reste un seul de ce type.

> Il *ne* reste *que* ce 'truc',

- Sans le *plus*, c'est la totalité de *ce qui reste*.
- On fait le constat de la situation.

  > C'est tout ce qu'il reste des objets déposés ici.

Comment: There is only one more of these things vs. There is only this thing left.

Comment: Le _plus_ insiste-t-il sur l'unicité ou sur le changement d'état « plusieurs » -> « un seul » ? (ce qui correspond bien à la traduction « _no longer_ »)

Comment: @Chop -- Réponse de normand ! En effet, il me semble que ces deux mots sont le recto et le verso d'un constat : l'unicité évoqué n'est pas une unicité d'objet, mais de groupe : "il ne reste plus que *ceux*-là", ce qui peut induire un changement d'état : on est passé de plusieurs à un groupe. C'est le contexte qui vous donnera le point de vue de l'auteur. J'ai complété ma réponse avec constat/valorisation